# Attaching a file to google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to attach a file to google sheets. I found several scripts that do so, but you have to know the folder id that you want the file to go into in google drive. I have a script I am working on that I need help with. The script gets stuck on showing the folder picker, an not passing the folder id to the script to place the file in the folder.

**code.gs**

```
 // upload document into google spreadsheet
// and put link to it into current cell

function onOpen(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push({name: "File...", functionName: "doGet"});
  ss.addMenu("Attach ...", menuEntries);
}

function doGet(e) {
  getOAuthToken;
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("upload attachment into Google Drive");
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app);
  var form = app.createFormPanel().setId('frm').setEncoding('multipart/form-data');
  var formContent = app.createVerticalPanel();
  form.add(formContent);  
  formContent.add(app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));

  // these parameters need to be passed by form
  // in doPost() these cannot be found out anymore
  formContent.add(app.createHidden("activeCell", SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getA1Notation()));
  formContent.add(app.createHidden("activeSheet", SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName()));
  formContent.add(app.createHidden("activeSpreadsheet", SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()));
  formContent.add(app.createSubmitButton('Submit'));
  app.add(form);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app);
  return app;
}

function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.createLabel('saving...');
  var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
  var doc = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B0uw1JCogWHuc29FWFJMWmc3Z1k').createFile(fileBlob);
  var label = app.createLabel('file uploaded successfully');

  // write value into current cell
  var value = 'hyperlink("' + doc.getUrl() + '";"' + doc.getName() + '")'
  var activeSpreadsheet = e.parameter.activeSpreadsheet;
  var activeSheet = e.parameter.activeSheet;
  var activeCell = e.parameter.activeCell;
  var label = app.createLabel('file uploaded successfully');
  app.add(label);
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(activeSpreadsheet).getSheetByName(activeSheet).getRange(activeCell).setFormula(value);
  app.close();
  return app;
}


function getOAuthToken() {
  DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
}
```

**Picker.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-
    ons.css">
      <script type="text/javascript">
    var DIALOG_DIMENSIONS = {
            width: 600,
            height: 425
        };
        var pickerApiLoaded = false;

    function onApiLoad() {
        gapi.load('picker', {
            'callback': function() {
                pickerApiLoaded = true;
            }
        });
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createPicker)
            .withFailureHandler(showError).getOAuthToken();
    }

    function createPicker(token) {

        if (pickerApiLoaded && token) {

            var docsView = new google.picker.DocsView()
                .setIncludeFolders(true)
                .setMimeTypes('application/vnd.google-apps.folder')
                .setSelectFolderEnabled(true);

            var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                .addView(docsView)
                .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
                .hideTitleBar()
                .setSize(DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.width - 2, DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.height - 2)
                .setOAuthToken(token)
                .setCallback(pickerCallback)
                .setOrigin('https://docs.google.com')
                .build();

            picker.setVisible(true);

        } else {
            showError('Unable to load the file picker.');
        }
    }

    /**
     * A callback function that extracts the chosen document's metadata from the
     * response object. For details on the response object, see
     * https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/result
     *
     * @param {object} data The response object.
     */
    function pickerCallback(data) {
        var action = data[google.picker.Response.ACTION];
        if (action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
            var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
            var id = doc[google.picker.Document.ID];
            // Show the ID of the Google Drive folder
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = id;
            google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(useData) // this will call the google apps script function in your Code.gs file
            .doSomething(fileId);
        } else if (action == google.picker.Action.CANCEL) {
            google.script.host.close();
        }
    }

    function showError(message) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Error: ' + message;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <p id='result'></p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask]. Regarding the code, it's includes UiApp which is a deprecated method. Reference https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app